# how to append without using buffer or append method?

Tags: java

```
/*
 * Compares user input and checks whether they are anagrams
 * 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Anagram
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter first sentence: ");
String s1 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter second sentence: ");
String s2 = sc.nextLine();

s1.toLowerCase();
String new1 = "";
for( char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i <s1.length(); i++){
    if(ch == s1.charAt(i)){
      System.out.print(ch + " are the letters of " + s1 + " in order ");
      break;
    }
  }
}
s2.toLowerCase();
String new2 = new String();
for( char ch2 = 'a'; ch2 <= 'z'; ch2++){
  int i2;
  for(i2 = 0; i2 <s2.length(); i2++){
    if(ch2 == s2.charAt(i2)){
      System.out.print(ch2 + " are the letters of " + s2 + " in order ");
      break;
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

In reference to my question before to which this is the proper way of doing the homework everything works fine except im having trouble creating a new string and passing all the chars to the new string. However this has to be done without using stringbuffer or append() is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+` operator that concatenates strings. But I think it is not the purpose of homework. It seems that you are expected to create char array and then create string using this array.

But that's it, man. If it is a homework you have now enough tips. Do it yourself and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: no it only says create a new empty string(ready to store each letter in alphabetical order) if the char matches the letter, append it to the new string since we havent learnt about arrays yet we not allowed to use it

Comment: @Ron_ish In that case use the `+` or `+=` operator as suggested.

Comment: used however it prints one char + the next one on different lines and so on and doesn't convert it as a string

Comment: It looks like 'new1' and 'new2' are your new strings.  You say that the assignment says "append it to the new string", but I don't see any code that does this.  Consider:  How would you do "append it to the new string"?

Comment: @ jeff i tried new1 += ch; same for the second one but it still doesn;t want to append